# Can't use User-Defined Table Type as a parameter in procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, permissions, user-defined-types

I am working on a database in SQL Server and want to create a procedure similar to this:

```
create procedure db.insert_data
    @variable db.user_defined_type readonly
as
begin
    -- code
end;
```

This fails with the following error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Procedure insert_data, Line 2
> Cannot find the type 'user_defined_type', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

However all the examples below work, which basically are creating a procedure without a user - defined table as parameter and running it, and using a user - defined table for a variable and inserting / selecting data from it:

```
create procedure db.insert_data
    @variable int
as
begin
    -- code
end;
go

exec db.insert_data '1'
```

```
declare @variable db.user_defined_type

insert into @variable (col1, col2)
values (1, 2)

select * from @variable
```

For permissions, I have been added to a certain role - group which has been granted pretty much every action on the databases. Is this a permission issue? Is there a particular permission that I need for this to work? If yes, how can I check which one to request for it?

Adding the whole script with CREATEs below as well for troubleshooting (I create a table which I use the procedure for too):

```
create table db.test_table(
    col1 nvarchar(3),
    col2 nvarchar(10),
    col3 nvarchar(35),
    col4 nvarchar(35),
    primary key (col1, col2)
);

GO

create type db.test_type as table(
    col1 nvarchar(3),
    col2 nvarchar(10),
    col3 nvarchar(35),
    col4 nvarchar(35),
    primary key (col1, col2)
);

GO

create procedure db.test_insert
@test_var db.test_type readonly
as
begin
--code
select null
end;
```

Comment: Provide a full [mre]; you don't include the definition of your user defined table type here.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PjUwrEhM)

Comment: Do you create procedure in another database than your table type? Because that's not allowed. Or is your table type created in model db? What does `select db_name(), * from sys.table_types` display?

Comment: Aside: Curious documentation on [Permissions and Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#Permissions). Must have `EXECUTE` _and_ `REFERENCES` permissions.

Comment: @ThomA I added the type creation as well. 
A fiddle equivalent example: https://dbfiddle.uk/gnfA9sK9
Can't reproduce the error either.

Comment: @siggemannen Everything is in the same database. What do you mean by created in model db? 'select db_name(), * from sys.table_types' displays the same database (db) in the first column for all table types.

Comment: @HABO any other tips - material on granting and viewing permissions in t-sql? I can't seem to find something thorough and they are far from straight-forward.

Comment: Hmm, but "db" is not database, it's the SCHEMA of the object. The naming is [database].[schema].[name]. Table types are not cross database objects.

Comment: @siggemannen sorry my bad, yes it's in the same database, forget the parenthesis. Tried to use the sample variables as reference and got it mixed up.

Comment: Have you used [`select * from sys.fn_my_permissions( 'db.user_defined_type', 'OBJECT' );`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: @HABO Ok, apparently I have no permission on object / schema level because my role has permissions on database level, so naturally that returned nothing.
However, I rechecked my database permissions, and turns out even though I had like 100 permissions, I didn't have References. Once they granted me that, issue got fixed. Thanks man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My permissions were granted through a database role. The role didn't have REFERENCES permission, hence I couldn't use parameters in my procedures.

Admin granted the role REFERENCES permission through the code below and I was able to create the procedure:

`USE db_name; GRANT REFERENCES TO db_role;`